# React native webview throws webkit version warning

Tags: react-native, webkit, react-native-webview

I'm working with `react-native-webview` to show an external site in my app, but the following warning message is showing each time the `webview` is loaded.

The code of the component is not complex, just `<WebView source={{ uri: 'example.com' }} />`

I couldn't find any reference to this. Does anyone know what can I do to remove the message?

[image: Webkit warning message]

Edit: After some tests, the webview only shows the message when it loads our website public pages, with other urls it works fine. Can it be any configuration in our site that I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of react-native-webview are you using? And also, are you using the community version?

Comment: I'm using version `11.0.2` but tried uptating to the last 5 versions and the message persists

Comment: @EduardoMartínez what's the url you are tying to load ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very minimal expo project with [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) (v11.17.1) and it's working absolutely fine.

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />
  );
}
```

Working screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kORE.jpg)